# Is it possible to define and load new types into the Hybris type system without restarting the server?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Let's say a new CMS Component type needs to be defined. In order to do that, the standard steps are:

1. Define the new type into *${extensionName}-items.xml*
2. Stop the server (If it is up and running)
3. Perform a build so that model and Jalo classes are being generated(for the new type) and compiled -> this takes approx **4 min**
4. Start the server back again  -> this takes approx **8 minutes**
5. Perform "Update Running System" so that the DB will know about the newly defined type.

The above described steps take **a lot of time**.

Is it possible to define new types and load them into the Hybris type system without restarting the server **in order to speed up the development process** ?

Comment: I've heard about some application which builds only the class you want but you have to pay for it, otherwise I don't think you can load them without building. One solution to speed up the development process could be a new CPU .. but again, you have to invest money..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can now be achieved(**and saves approximately ten minutes used on build and server start**) by using a custom ANT target and JRebel.

Please check the following [explanation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHtMg8vZfdI&feature=youtu.be) which depicts how to define and load new types into the Hybris Type System without restarting the server **using JRebel**.

Please also check this [documentation](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s739/client/snv?noteGuid=af843d3a-0dfb-416f-92af-04010b3cf56a&noteKey=cb0e6cba036b1f5d18bb1e4bbeabc2de&sn=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.evernote.com%2Fshard%2Fs739%2Fsh%2Faf843d3a-0dfb-416f-92af-04010b3cf56a%2Fcb0e6cba036b1f5d18bb1e4bbeabc2de&title=Setup%2Bsteps%2Bcopy) as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to define and load new types into the Hybris type
>   system without restarting the server?

The answer is yes, you can define new item type using backoffice/hmc types in order to use it on the fly. But the system will not generate all the classes.

> Is it possible to define new types and load them into the Hybris type
>   system without restarting the server **in order to speed up the
>   development process ?**

The answer is no, for the new item type development you need the system generated classes in order to deal with the business logic, which only possible with the steps you have mentioned.

---

If your question is, how can we speed up the development process with SAP Hybris?

- There are few products available in the market, which boost development speed by loading all your changes without restarting the server like [Jrebel](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.6.0.0/en-US/8be5ab06866910149c83e0bd4a187fd8.html), [DCEVM](https://help.sap.com/viewer/DRAFT/29be7c30ab264e4d98821f04dd07ef2b/6.5.0.0/en-US/0b40907d5db14955bf4074b4b25e6998.html), [fakereplace](https://github.com/fakereplace/fakereplace) etc.  Jrebel is paid but you will get ROI.
- You can see a significant difference if you use a system having Linux OS, multi-core CPU, SSD hard disk, DB other than HSQL.
- Below are some tricks & tips

  - [speed up server start time](https://hybrismart.com/2016/12/27/speed-up-server-start-time/)
  - [prevent Grunt from being executed](https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/speed-up-build-process-of-hybris-6-x/)
  - [reducing compile time](https://hybrismart.com/2020/02/12/sap-commerce-reducing-compile-time/)
  - [question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289485/how-could-i-reduce-the-hybris-server-startup-time)

Comment: thank you for your accurate answer and for the very helpful references that you provided. I have just finished developing a custom ant target which can be used along with JRebel in order to achieve this. Please check my answer